# dotted border style when I click on something

Tags: css

I have a tabs components in my webpage and when I select one of the tabs I call the ui-tabs-selected class to give it a special behavior :

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected {
    background: transparent !important;
    color: #444 !important;
    border-top-color: #3c8dbc;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-left-color: #f4f4f4;
    border-right-color: #f4f4f4;
}
```

The problem is that when I select a tab I get a dotted border style, as you can see in this picture:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

But this dotted border style disappears when I click somewhere else on the page.

How can I get rid of this effect ?

Comment: I think what you're needing is a pseudo selector http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: When the tab is clicked, a `focus` state is applied to the element. You need to change the way that focus is handled. Inspect the element in your dev tools to see what it looks like when there is a border around it and when there isn't. See comment above, there is usually a pseudo selector declared for it.

Comment: I think that this can be solved with the outline style by setting it to 0. It should remove this dotted outline. I have added this as an answer to this question. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-tabs{
   outline:none !important;
}
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the outline style, set it to 0 to remove it.

```
.ui-tabs{
   outline: 0;
}
```